# In Regex, how do to add one extra space between every word?

Tags: .net, regex, space

I have a sentence say

```
"This is my new program"
```

I want to convert it to

```
"This  is  my  new  program"
```

i.e, extra space after every word.

**How can I achieve this using Regex in .net ?**

This has to be generic. Say for example if the number of spaces are 4 between words, it should make it 5.

Comment: wouldn't it be a lot easier to do it without regular expressions, i.e. using [`String.Replace( " ", "  " )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: @Shaw - The problem is there might be sentences in which the number of spaces between words might be 2 or 3 or 4 or n. I always want to add 1 extra space. Say for example: if there are 4 spaces, I want to make it 5.

Comment: That's actually extra space between words. If it had been after, there should've been a space after "program" and if it had been before, there should've been a space before "This".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"\s+", " $0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `Regex`? Why don't you use `Replace` method on the string itself?

Comment: The problem is there might be sentences in which the number of spaces between words might be 2 or 3 or 4 or n. I always want to add 1 extra space. Say for example: if there are 4 spaces, I want to make it 5.

Comment: @abhinav: `[?!\s][\s]*` matches one of `?`, `!` or a whitespace character, followed by zero or more whitespace characters.  I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: my bad, intended to do a negative lookahead. Messed up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this. Although I think that @LukeH solution is better if you don't have some other spaces that you want to leave untouched.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\b\w+\b)(?!$)", "$1 ");
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
(        # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \b       # Assert position at a word boundary
   \w       # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \b       # Assert position at a word boundary
)
(?!      # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   $        # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "\ {1}", "  ")
```

This replaces each instance of a single (and only single) space with two spaces.

Comment: This will not work for me since it replaces every instance by 2 spaces. I want to add just 1 extra space between those words !